# AnonymoX /etc/hosts override

Tags: networking, server, firefox

I have some sites blocked via `/etc/hosts-entries`. My problem is, that after activating AnonymoX, Firefox can still reach these sites. I tried to block the sites for the fake-ips in the hosts file, but without success.
For example:

```
127.0.0.1 www.website.com
186.79.175.220 www.website.com
```

First entry successfully blocks website when AnonymoX is disabled.
Second entry fails when browsing with fake-ip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AnonymoX is an add-on for Firefox that allows you to browse websites through their own network of proxy servers.

That means, your computer connects to an AnonymoX server and sends it the HTTP request. The AnonymoX server then connects to the requested website's real host server, passes your anonymized request on to it with its own AnonymoX IP address as source. The real web server processes the request and sends the answer (e.g. HTML website) back to the AnonymoX proxy, which redirects it back to your own machine.

So to your computer, it looks like the AnonymoX proxy is the web server responding to your requests, while to the real web servers, the AnonymoX proxy looks like the one who visits their sites.

That means that the web servers can't identify you as visitor, but also implies that you yourself don't have direct contact with their servers and therefore can't block them by their IPs, because you don't connect to those IPs any more but to the AnonymoX ones. You also can't block them by their URL by manually resolving them to your localhost or a fake IP with `/etc/hosts-entries` or other system-wide DNS manipulations, because AnonymoX handles all the DNS resolving, as otherwise you would connect to the web servers directly. Your browser sends all requests uniformly to AnonymoX.

What you can do is to filter sites *before* the request gets passed to AnonymoX, e.g. by another add-on that filters outgoing requests and blocks URLs in your browser. Or you could add another proxy server *after* AnonymoX which is able to filter sites, so that your computer communicates with the AnonymoX proxy, that communicates with the second, filtering proxy, which finally communicates with the real web servers.